# How to make gitlab-ci fail when there is an sql error?

Tags: gitlab, sh, gitlab-ci

The goal is to make the gitlab-ci fail when there is an sql error.

toto.sql

```
select 1 from idontexist -- generate sql error
```

toto.sh

```
@toto.sql
```

gitlab-ci.yaml

```
script:
    - |
      chmod +x ./toto.sh
      ./toto.sh
```

How can I detect this sql error to make job fail?

the job result has no error in gitlab ci:

```
$ chmod +x 
./toto.sh 
SQL Error [942] [42000]: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Job succeeded
```

Comment: Check exit code of toto.sh. Normally, the job should fail if it's not zero. To debug you can print it with echo $?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an important part in the sql file:

```
sqlplus /nolog << EOF
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
```

with these lines, the error code is retrieve correctly